# Deserialize PHP array in coldfusion

Tags: php, wordpress, coldfusion

I'm working on a Coldfusion project where I need to pull some information from a wordpress powered database.  Some of the information that I need is in a serialized array stored in the wp_options table.  I can't figure out how to deserialize the array data in Coldfusion.

I'm currently using the dev version of Coldfusion 8.  I can't upgrade to Coldfusion 9 since my works application is build on Coldfusion 8

I've only been able to find this link http://www.cfinsider.com/index.cfm/2010/5/4/Serializing--Deserializing-in-ColdFusion-9 which talks about deserializing CFC's but it doesn't seem to work on the array I'm passing.

Here is an example of the data I'm trying to deserialze

```
a:2:{i:2;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:6:"number";i:5;}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can serialize the PHP array into a JSON string, you can use deserializeJson on the CF side.

Comment: I'd follow this path if possible.

Comment: agreed - PHP can export JSON, and virtually every other language can import it. That's definitely the preferred format.

Comment: Thanks,  This was a simple solution I completely looked over.  I was able to write a quick plugin that stores a copy of the widget data in JSON.

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet might be to check out Sean Corfield's [scripting for ColdFusion](http://scripting.riaforge.org/) project.  I was able to do the following with it:

```
<script:php>
    <?php
        $array = unserialize('a:2:{i:2;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:6:"number";i:5;}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}');
        $_COLDFUSION["test"] = json_encode($array);
    ?>
</script:php>

<cfdump var="#deserializeJSON(variables.test)#">
```

Which produced:

[image]

Comment: you could take it a step further and set the string in CF and pull it back out on the php side like so:

<cfset serializedString = 'a:2:{i:2;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:6:"number";i:5;}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}' />

$array = unserialize($_COLDFUSION["serializedString"]);

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's a result of PHP serialization - I assume CF uses a completely different process. The schema seems pretty straightforward:

```
datatype:size:structure
```

or

```
numbertype:numbervalue
```

so

```
a:2:{i:2;s:3:"foo"}
```

would mean "array of size 2 { integer 2 ; string 'foo' of size 3 }". Note that arrays can be nested, and things can get complicated with Objects and other serialized classes (see [PHP's manual on serializing objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php)).