# Sean Corfield's Scripting For ColdFusion Project Tag Doesn't Work When Passing Php Array String In From A ColdFusion Query

Tags: php, coldfusion

I'm having an issue using Sean Corfield's scripting for ColdFusion project to desearialize a php array using ColdFusion. I discovered this convenient custom tag at [Deserialize PHP array in coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511184/deserialize-php-array-in-coldfusion) while looking for a solution. But here is my problem. I can't get it to work when passing in the php array string via a coldfusion query. See my issue below...

This works fine...

```
    <cfsavecontent variable="teststring">a:1:{i:0;a:10:{s:2:"id";s:4:"2152";s:12:"variation_id";s:4:"2153";s:4:"name";s:18:"100 Wiki Backlinks";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:9:"item_meta";a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:9:"meta_name";s:25:"pa_is-your-website-a-wiki";s:10:"meta_value";s:11:"im-not-sure";}i:1;a:2:{s:9:"meta_name";s:30:"pa_url-to-your-target-web-page";s:10:"meta_value";s:51:"http://www.deluxerubberstamp.com/petid/petidtag.htm";}i:2;a:2:{s:9:"meta_name";s:25:"pa_enter-up-to-5-keywords";s:10:"meta_value";s:68:"pet id tags, animal id tags, pet supplies, dog id tags,cat id tags
";}}s:13:"line_subtotal";s:2:"29";s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";s:1:"0";s:10:"line_total";s:2:"29";s:8:"line_tax";s:1:"0";s:9:"tax_class";s:9:"zero-rate";}}</cfsavecontent>

<script:php>
    <?php

        $array = unserialize('<cfoutput>#teststring#</cfoutput>');
        $_COLDFUSION["greeting"] = json_encode($array);

    ?>
</script:php>

<cfdump var="#deserializeJSON(greeting)#">
```

But this doesn't work and simply returns "NO" in the dump, as if the json isn't valid or something...

```
<cfquery datasource="#request.dsname#" username="#request.dsuser#" password="#request.dspassword#" name="getorder" >
SELECT phparrayorderdetail FROM tbl_orders WHERE orderid = '1'
</cfquery>

<cfsavecontent variable="teststring">#trim(getorder.phparrayorderdetail)#</cfsavecontent>

<script:php>
    <?php

        $array = unserialize('<cfoutput>#teststring#</cfoutput>');
        $_COLDFUSION["greeting"] = json_encode($array);

    ?>
</script:php>
```

NOTE that I can use...

```
<cfoutput>#getorder.phparrayorderdetail#</cfoutput>
```

or

```
<cfdump var="#getorder.phparrayorderdetail#">
```

to output the php array in my browser and it is identical to the php array string that you see above. I can actually copy it and paste it into the unserialize() function as shown above and once again the script works just fine. I can't figure out as to why it doesn't work when passing in the php array string via a coldfusion query. Is there some other kind of formatting that I have to do to the php array string on ColdFusion side before passing it in to get this to work?

Thanks very much for any advice or recommendations.

Comment: unserialize not throwing any errors? Can you debug somehow what PHP actually gets as a parameter, by putting `<cfoutput>#teststring#</cfoutput>` between your `<script:php>` tag and `<?php`

Comment: That's a very old, unmaintained library that was created for CF8 and hasn't been updated since. It was written as a proof of concept and was never intended to be particularly sophisticated. I'd welcome anyone taking it over and updating it.

Comment: That said... There must be some difference between the string representations that you're just not seeing. Add the original cfsavecontent back in (storing in teststring1) and then compare the strings at runtime and see if CFML thinks they are equal - I bet they are not.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks very much for your valuable feedback.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks very much for your valuable feedback. @Sean Corfield thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out and you are correct! When comparing what appears to be the same value as returned from the ColdFusion query and the same hard coded value as a variable, ColdFusion sees the the two values as being different. Very strange! I don't get it. Because I can output the value returned from the query and then copy and paste it in as a hard coded value and it works.